# Weird posix message queue linking issue - sometimes it doesn't link correctly

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix, message-queue

When I build the following code, it builds fine. If I change the code to comment out the "while", using the same command line, it does not build (see below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   while (1) { }

   mq_open("/YouSUCK", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG, NULL);

   return 0;
}

dada@thud:~/RaspberryPI$ gcc -g -Wall -lrt -o mqtest mqtest.c

dada@thud:~/RaspberryPI$ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//   while (1) { }

   mq_open("/YouSUCK", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG, NULL);

   return 0;
}

dada@thud:~/RaspberryPI$ gcc -g -Wall -lrt -o mqtest mqtest.c

/tmp/cccw376u.o: In function `main':

/home/dada/RaspberryPI/mqtest.c:7: undefined reference to `mq_open'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

dada@thud:~/RaspberryPI$
```

Any ideas ?

```
dada@thud:~/RaspberryPI$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

Update:

Looks like a compiler version issue, I built the same code on a different box, and it builds properly with either of the above files. So I guess I need a different compiler.

```
dada@JoesPi ~ $ gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
```

Comment: Looks like a ciompiler verion issues, I built the same code on a different box,

Comment: Maybe the compiler optimized it out because the `mq_open` will never be executed.

Comment: @duck It doesn't seem like that would be the case, since if it is optimized away then there should be no undefined symbol since it is in effect no longer there.

Comment: You said above that it didn't compile once you commented it out but that it had compiled with it there.  With the endless while loop maybe the compiler just the chucked `mq_open` out entirely, hence no symbol to choke on.

Comment: Sorry I understand now... read your comment backwards, thanks I will try a few other things to see if that is the case.

Comment: Ok, yes when I change from while(1) to while(0) I get the changed behavior, so I think you are correct about the optimizer. now I just need to find out why the compiler does not find mq_open, when I am including -lrt on the command line.

Comment: From the GCC manual: "It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded."  This what your "gcc -g -Wall -lrt -o mqtest mqtest.c" does as I commented below.

Comment: @Duck - Yes, sorry you pointed that out earlier but I glossed over it with my blinders on. Thanks Again, that seems to have solved the problem, it builds now. (Now to put the app back together and get it to work again)

Comment: You're welcome Joe.  Good luck with the reassembly.

Comment: put -lrt at end and it will work..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 'undefined reference to mq_open' collect2:

Link agaist librt.  E.G. `-lrt`

Comment: Thanks, I am-from above... "gcc -g -Wall -lrt -o mqtest mqtest.c" that is what the weird behavior is... the top example builds, the bottom does not, same exact command line...

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.  Change to `gcc -g -Wall -o mqtest mqtest.c -lrt`.  I could not reproduce your problem.  Both compiled.

Comment: Thanks @Duck. Looks like a compiler version issue, the first 2 boxes I tried it on I got the same issue, on the 3rd it worked fine. Going to try to fix the compiler on the bad box. Thanks Again - Joe

Comment: @Duck I am not able to specify lrt inside pkg-config for g++. It says lrt library is not found. Any ideas?

Comment: @Duck I have the above issue documented here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094210/makefile-g-lrt-problem-cannot-find-lrt

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it using $gcc -g -Wall -o mqtest mqtest.c **-lrt** to make it work without compilation errors as undefined reference for posix message queue apia.
(as mentioned in the comments )

Answer (score 0):

**Acutally if you use -lrt before c file there is error**

root@embsys-VirtualBox:~# gcc -lrt test.c

/tmp/ccR93VIp.o: In function `tfunc':
test.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to`mq_getattr'
test.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `mq_receive'
/tmp/ccR93VIp.o: In function`main':
test.c:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `mq_open'
test.c:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to`mq_notify'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**This works**

root@embsys-VirtualBox:~# gcc  test.c -lrt